# Percentile with multiple conditions in google sheets

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, error-handling, percentile

I have a sheet called "main" with 4 columns like this :
[image]

I want to make a percentile of column N, with condition of column A, C, and J

I tried with function `PERCENTILE(IF((x)*(y)*(z),aa),0.5)` and **works** for

queue_name = "idecbi-prod",

grass_week = "2022-09-05",

and task_user = "di_scheduler",

Desired Answer :
[image]

it works just fine with these conditions,

But when I tried to use another condition such as "idecbi-dev" or "ad-hoc" or another grass_week, it become error like this

[image]

Whereas the only thing i change is only O4 to O5 and N4 to N5

The data seems fine and we have all the conditions as shown in the first picture (main sheet).

Is there anything that I miss ?

Here's dummy data that I've created for better understanding.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ejhxVTayWjrUAZ6NE78AXx2pENvlhGDstMXwrDfqv_0/edit?usp=sharing

I'm trying to make cell D4 works as fine as D3

Comment: Please provide a minimal example see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ejhxVTayWjrUAZ6NE78AXx2pENvlhGDstMXwrDfqv_0/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the link 
you can use "trial sheet".
I'm trying to make cell D4 works as fine as D3

Comment: did you try to wrap it into ARRAYFORMULA ?

Comment: @JohanKlemantan Please include your desierd output in the question.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. Use [Markdown Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892)-all the data needed to answer your question must be in the question itself. [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Please see [mcve]. To quote, `Use simple, descriptive names for functions and variables – don’t copy the names you’re using in your existing code.` Restart from scratch.

Comment: @JohanKlemantan Where did I solved this question i dont remember, could you include the link? or you mean Player0 [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73920709/percentile-with-multiple-conditions-in-google-sheets?noredirect=1#comment130522177_73920709) ?

Comment: Oopps sorry, yeah I mean @player0, thank you bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap it into ARRAYFORMULA:

```
=ArrayFormula(PERCENTILE(IF((main_week=A3)*(main_queue=C4)*(main_task_usage=B4),main_avg_exectime),0.5))
```

[image]